# Performance and index usage for function based queries and function calls inside functions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, plv8

I'm trying to improve the performance of PostgreSQL functions and function calls inside functions.

In our application, PostgreSQL (9.6) queries are totally based on functions. For example, in order to fetch a lot of "items" some code as the lines below might be used:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.item_read_one(
    "itemID" integer)
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    outputvariable jsonb;
BEGIN
  SELECT row_to_json (my_subquery) FROM (
   SELECT
   id,
   "simpleField1",
   "simpleField2",
   item_status(id,"crucialField") AS status
   FROM item_table
   WHERE id = $1 AND deleted IS NOT TRUE)
 AS my_subquery into outputvariable ;
RETURN outputvariable;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.item_read_one(integer)
  OWNER TO some_user;
```

You see, inside the inner `SELECT` there is - beside some simple fields - another function call. These inner functions are usually plv8 based and contain a lot of JavaScript logic, including database queries. An example might look like such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.item_status(
    "itemID" integer,
    "crucialField" text)
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$BODY$

var returnStatus = {};
var myVariable;
if(crucialField == 'foo') {
  myVariable = plv8.execute('SELECT something FROM other_table WHERE "itemID" = $1',[itemID]);
}

else if(crucialField == 'sweetKitten') {
  myVariable = plv8.execute('SELECT "somethingElse" FROM kitten WHERE "itemID" = $1',[itemID]);
}

/*
 A lot more JavaScript logic here. But you get the idea, I hope.
*/

return returnStatus;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plv8 IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.item_status(integer, text)
  OWNER TO some_user;
```

Aside from the question, whether this design makes sense, the problem is: How to improve the performance?

The data returned by functions like item_status is pretty stable, so it could make sense to put it into an index, but I don't know how.

PostgreSQL version used is 9.6.

Comment: `item_read_one()` can be changed into a plain SQL function (instead of PL/pgSQL) which gives the optimizer more possibilities to optimize it.

Comment: You should **not** mark functions that retrieve values from the database as `immutable`. Your example only contains `select` statements, so you could define it as `stable`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for those hints! The first one gave me about 10% improvement in one case. However, the other hint didn't affect the performance in may case.

Comment: Not marking the function immutable has nothing to do with performance - it has to do with correctness.